Is a Non-Homogenous Poisson Process many Homogenous Poisson Processes in Disguise?
I am trying to learn about Poisson Processes.
As I understand:

The number of events in time $T$ follows a Poisson distribution:

$$N(T) \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda T)$$

Given $N(T) = n$ events occur in $[0,T]$, these event times $(T_1,...,T_n)$ follow a $n$ independent uniform random variables on $[0,T]$:

$$T_1,...,T_n | N(T)=n \sim \text{Uniform}[0,T]_{(1:n)}$$
In terms of simulation:

First generate the total number of events $N$ that occur in $[0,T]$ from a Poisson distribution: $N \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda T)$
Then, given we have $N$ events, generate their times as uniform random variables and sort them: $T_1,...,T_N | N \sim \text{Uniform}[0,T]_{(1:n)}$

I did this in R:

I am wondering, how to do this for a Non-Homogenous Poisson Process?
This is similar to the earlier Poisson Process but the rate parameter $\lambda$ is now a function of time $\lambda(t)$.

The number of events in any interval $(t, t+h]$ follows a Poisson distribution with mean $\int_t^{t+h} \lambda(s)ds$:

$$P(N(t+h) - N(t) = k) = \frac{e^{-\int_t^{t+h} \lambda(s)ds}(\int_t^{t+h} \lambda(s)ds)^k}{k!}, \quad k = 0,1,2,...$$
Suppose I define some rate function that depends on time. Mathematically, does it make sense to calculate the rate function at different times (discretization) and stitch together multiple homogenous Poisson processes to make a non-homogenous Poisson process?
For example, I performed this simulation based on the above logic in R:

Is this idea correct?

PS: R code available in case anyone wants to see it (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79173958/simulating-a-non-homogenous-poisson-process)


Just a comment: provided $h$ is small enough, another way to simulate is to set $N_0=0$ then $N_{h}=N_0+1$ with chance $\lambda h$ and $N_h=N_0$ with chance $1-\lambda h$. Repeat for $2h,3h,...$ etc. For a non-homogeneous process, you just need to compute $\int_t^{t+h} \lambda(s) ds$, for $t=0,h,2h,\dotsc$.
I think once the rate is non-homogeneous the property that $T_i $ are uniform conditional on $N_t$ is destroyed.

thank you for this feedback! do you think what I did was correct?

There is a very simple method to check if what you did was correct: run your code and see if $N_T$ is Poisson with parameter $\lambda T,.$

@KurtG. : thank you for reminding me! this makes perfect sense!
